# Disable Meteor.user() details on browser console

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to disable the details within `Meteor.user()` on **Browser console** in production mode?

Below is the snapshot of what I see when I deploy my code in production. This is very insecure as far as client details are concerned.

[image: Below is the image]

Comment: Note that depending on how you publish a user will only be able to see their own details, not the info of others. You want to publish more about the logged-in user and almost nothing about the others.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't publish sensitive data to client, keep your logic regarding user memberships on server.

Comment: I am doing the same. But if you see the command I am actually viewing only my data on browser console.

Comment: 1. Data under "profile" key in user document is published to client automatically.

2. If you have autopublish package enabled - all the data is automatically published to client.

Comment: is there a way to hide everthing on browser console if user gives a command `Meteor.user()` ?

Comment: No, you can not do that.

Comment: Why? Why can't I do that?

Comment: The console has access to everything your client code has access to. If you send data to the client, assume an attacker can and will see it.

Comment: I never put anything on the `users` collection because of its accessibility on the client. Usually I'll create a separate document, say `Account` and always put everything in there and link it back to the `users` collection with a `userId` field on the `Account` document

Comment: @AfifNajib Sorry what? You are the one who controls what is accessed on client and what is not. Publications and subscriptions are meant for that. If you have user document with field "superSensetiveCCNumber" of course you can just exclude it from user data publication.

Comment: @ArtūrsLataks that's true for other collections, but in this case he's putting data into `Meteor.user().profile`, and that part is always published to the client. That's why I suggest creating a separate Collection for user details. Read up here for more info: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile

Comment: @AfifSohaili Look a my comment a bit higher, I know that user.profile is automatically published. Yet It doesn't mean that you can't store sensitive user data under another field and don't publish it, right?

Comment: @ArtūrsLataks sorry I am bad at double negations. You mean he should just store the sensitive user data on a different and just don't publish it to the client?

Comment: @AfifSohaili yes, this is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save sensitive data in `Meteor.user()`.

Rather make another **Collection** then associate it through **_id**.

Use Publish And Subscribe carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the `profile` field on a `Meteor.users` document, **since that is always published to the client.**

See here: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile

What I would suggest is to move all the sensitive data from the `profile` field and into the top-level key of the `users` document.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // with document:
  // Document {
  //   _id: '123',
  //   services: { /* */ },
  //   profile: { /* */ },
  //   subscription: { /* */ }
  // }

  Meteor.publish('users.subscriptions', function(userId) {
    return Users.find({ _id: userId }, { fields: { subscription: 1 }})
  })
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.home.onCreated(function() {
    this.autorun(() => {
      console.log(Meteor.user().subscription) // `undefined` at this point
      this.subscribe('users.subscriptions', Meteor.userId(), function() {
        console.log(Meteor.user().subscription) // returns user's subscription
      })
    })
  })
}
```

You can make use of libraries such as `percolate:migrations` to migrate the data to top-level key.

```
meteor add percolate:migrations
```

And then:

```
// server/migrations/1-move-all-profile-info-to-top-level.js
import _ from 'meteor/underscore'

Migrations.add({
  version: 1,
  up: function() {
    _.each(Meteor.users.find().fetch(), function(user) {
      Meteor.update(user._id, {
        $set: {
          subscription: user.profile.subscription,
          // other fields that needs migrating
          profile: null // empty out the profile field
        }
      })
    })
  }
})

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Migrations.migrateTo('latest')
})
```